# What is a correct way to implement Fluent Validation for IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I'm struggling with implementation of validation for IFormFile. I'm using FluentValidation and here is my validator for FormFile:

```
    public class PhotoValidator : AbstractValidator<IFormFile>
    {
        private readonly PhotoSettings _settings;

        public PhotoValidator(IOptionsSnapshot<PhotoSettings> snapshot)
        {
            _settings = snapshot.Value;

            RuleFor(f => f).NotNull().WithMessage("Please Attach your photo");

            RuleFor(f => f.Length).ExclusiveBetween(0, _settings.MaxBytes)
                .WithMessage($"File length should be greater than 0 and less than {_settings.MaxBytes / 1024 / 1024} MB");

            RuleFor(f => f.FileName).Must(HaveSupportedFileType);
        }

        private bool HaveSupportedFileType(string fileName)
        {
            return _settings.IsSupported(fileName);
        }
    }
```

The problem is than during request validator isn't called at all, it just skips it.
Here is my api endpoint signatrue:

```
        [HttpPost("{productId:min(1)}")]
        public IActionResult Upload([FromRoute] int productId, IFormFile file)
        {
          // some code here
        }
```

In my project I have other validators (however they don't implement AbstractValidator with Interface type) and they are doing job. Is it even possible to validate type that implements interface?

Comment: Have you tried implementing AbstractValidator for FormFile?

Comment: @Neistow yes I did, but it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is than during request validator isn't called at all, it
> just skips it.

### Update

In addition to the manual trigger method, we can indeed let `PhotoValidator` function **trigger automatically** after submit.

The premise is that we need to **configure FluentValidation in the ConfigureServices method of startup** as follow:

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;// this need FluentValidation.AspNetCore dll
//...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // ...
   services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation();
   services.AddTransient<IValidator<FileData>, PhotoValidator>();
 }
```

Here is a good reference [document](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#getting-started) for your reference.

Besides, to verify the content of `IFormFile`, you need to put it into **a class as an object** to verify.

Here I created the `FileData` class and stored a field of IFormFile type as follows：

```
 public class FileData
    {
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

And, there are some details that need to be modified when verifying in PhotoValidator.

**When the file is null**, you need to add the precondition `When(f => f.file != null)` to the statement that validates the **Length and FileName** fields, otherwise an error will occur：

(*Since you did not provide the relevant content of `PhotoSettings`, I will set _settings.MaxBytes to a fixed value here*)：

```
 public class PhotoValidator : AbstractValidator<FileData>
    {
        private readonly PhotoSettings _settings;

        public PhotoValidator(/*PhotoSettings snapshot*/)
        {
            // _settings = snapshot;
            _settings = new PhotoSettings() { MaxBytes = 2048000 };
            RuleFor(f => f.file).NotNull().WithMessage("Please Attach your photo"); 
            RuleFor(f => f.file.Length).ExclusiveBetween(0, _settings.MaxBytes)
                .WithMessage($"File length should be greater than 0 and less than {_settings.MaxBytes / 1024 / 1024} MB")
                .When(f => f.file != null);

            RuleFor(f => f.file.FileName).Must(HaveSupportedFileType).When(f => f.file != null);
        }
        private bool HaveSupportedFileType(string fileName)
        {
            return _settings.IsSupported(fileName);
        } 
    }
```

Here is the controller:

```
    [HttpPost("{productId}")]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromRoute]int productId, FileData data)
    {
        string errorMessages = null;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {  
            errorMessages = ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.ValidationState == ModelValidationState.Invalid).FirstOrDefault()
                .Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage;
            return Content(errorMessages);//return error message to show in view
        } 
        return Ok();
    }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Upload</h1>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        productId: <input name="productId" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <span class="text-danger" id="fileMessage"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts{

    <script>
        $("form").submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var productId = $("input[name=productId]").val();
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $('input[name=file]')[0].files[0];
            fd.append('file', files);
            var data = {
                "file": fd,
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "/" + productId,
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (message) {
                    $("#fileMessage").html(message);
                    if (message == "") {
                       alert("upload Success!");
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    </script>

}
```

Here is the test result :

[image]

Comment: Still calling validator manually isn't a perfect solution. Is there any explanation why validator isn't called?

Comment: @Neistow, yes, I was trying to automatically trigger, just need to add some configuration in the startup, I have updated my reply, hope it can help you.

Comment: Sounds nice, I figured out it myself too, just wrapping IFormFile in a class does the job, also you don't even need to add IValidator in services, there is a convenient way for registering all validators at once. It looks like this:

`AddFluentValidation(fv =>fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<PersonValidator>());`